# While using Play Framework v1 and IntelliJ 13 CE and running jUnit tests, I receive an UnExpectedException during startup

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have been using IntelliJ CE for the past two weeks when suddenly I ran into problems running my unit tests within IntelliJ.  My team uses Play Framework v1.2.5 and if I run the project from the command line, it compiles and runs fine.  If I run the tests for the project in Eclipse Kepler, they work fine.  Only when I run the tests in IntelliJ, I receive this Exception during startup:

```
    play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@5d0a70af on models.PortfolioHoldingItem$Field$8
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:556)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:163)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:427)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:515)
    at play.test.PlayJUnitRunner.<init>(PlayJUnitRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer on models.PortfolioHoldingItem$Field$8
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:306)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:551)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Error in PropertiesEnhancer
    at play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer$1.edit(PropertiesEnhancer.java:177)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:198)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.instrument(CtBehavior.java:664)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(PropertiesEnhancer.java:135)
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:301)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: field: $assertionsDisabled in models.PortfolioHoldingItem$Field
    at javassist.CtClassType.checkGetField(CtClassType.java:907)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getField(CtClassType.java:896)
    at javassist.CtClass.getField(CtClass.java:699)
    at javassist.expr.FieldAccess.getField(FieldAccess.java:114)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.PropertiesEnhancer$1.edit(PropertiesEnhancer.java:142)
    ... 24 more
```

That class is in the project, but not being tested.  I've tried to:

1. play clean (delete the play cache)
2. play idealize (regenerate the IntelliJ project, re-import)
3. play eclipsify (regenerate the eclipse project, then import into IntelliJ)
4. From within IntelliJ, File | Invalidate Caches and Restart
5. Upgrade my JDK from 1.7.0_45 to 1.7.0_51
6. Upgrade to IntelliJ CE 13.1
7. Clone a new copy of the repo, re-import

I am on a mac, if that makes any difference.  Anyone else experience this?  Any suggestions for something to try?

EDIT: Same problem on my Linux dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution.  PlayFramework v1 has some issues with Java 7's verifier.

Adding -XX:-UseSplitVerifier to the jUnit Run/Debug configuration solved this issue.

[image: Run/Debug Configuration | Defaults | jUnit]